# Is there a word for taking a spouse's name?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a verb that describes adopting a name specifically when a spouse takes their partner's surname. I feel like there should be a word for it.

> When they married, Kate ____, but after the divorce, she retook her maiden name.

I've tried looking for this word on Onelook, Google, and Wikipedia without any luck. In the case that it doesn't exist, can anyone think of a neologism or portmanteau that could equate the meaning of adopting or taking a spouse's name?

Comment: I don't think so. You just *take your spouse's name*.

Comment: Kate surnamed herself.

Comment: Kate capitulated

Comment: Kate effaced herself.

Answer (score -2):

I don't think an English word exists, but since you suggested a neologism, how about **nomified** after the Latin *nomine* for "name"?